# Secondary Menu Tab (local task)

Tags: 6, routes

I was wondering if there is any good documentation out there on building second level tabs using the menu system. Here is some of the menu code in my module:

```
  $items['admin/settings/cvminterviews'] = array(
    'title' => 'Interview Scheduler',
    'description' => 'Overview',
    'file' => 'cvminterviews_admin_overview.inc.php',
    'page callback' => 'cvminterviews_overview_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer cvminterviews'),
  );

  $items['admin/settings/cvminterviews/overview'] = array(
    'title' => 'Overview',
    'description' => 'Overview',
    'file' => 'cvminterviews_admin_overview.inc.php',
    'page callback' => 'cvminterviews_overview_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer cvminterviews'),
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10
  );

  $items['admin/settings/cvminterviews/interviewers'] = array(
    'title' => 'Interviewers',
    'description' => 'Interviewers',
    'file' => 'cvminterviews_admin_interviewers.inc.php',
    'page callback' => 'cvminterviews_interviewers_overview_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer cvminterviews'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  $items['admin/settings/cvminterviews/interviewers/import'] = array(
    'title' => 'Import Interviewers',
    'description' => 'Import Interviewers',
    'file' => 'cvminterviews_admin_interviewers_import.inc.php',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('cvminterviews_interviewers_import_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer cvminterviews'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

I would like to have

> admin/settings/cvminterviews/interviewers/import

Be a secondary tab to:

> admin/settings/cvminterviews/interviewers

but the above code doesn't seem to do anything with it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following to my code:

```
  $items['admin/settings/cvminterviews/interviewers/interviewers'] = array(
    'title' => 'Interviewers',
    'description' => 'Interviewers',
    'file' => 'cvminterviews_admin_interviewers.inc.php',
    'page callback' => 'cvminterviews_interviewers_overview_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer cvminterviews'),
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

The important part is to make this the exact same callbacks as the `'admin/settings/cvminterviews/interviewers'` menu item, but with one more level, and assign the `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` type.